# Error while executing SSIS package in SQL. Directory is not specified in the file connection manager

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, ftp, connection

I am getting the error in SQL during package execution (Ftp task) and I have tried to find how to deal with that error but without any success. I wonder if anyone knows what is the problem. The package runs fine in Visual Studio. However, after deploying it into SQL I am getting this error:

```
{FTP Task Name}:Error:  
Directory is not specified in the file connection manager "{Your Variable Name}".
```

Any ideas why it is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: This link might help ... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d4b03b0-9783-4a08-950c-100276c9670f/ssis-package-ftp-task-error-directory-is-not-specified-in-the-file-connection-manager?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Your question is currently too vague to provide an answer. Please edit the question to identify how you have the FTP task configured. What are the design time and expected run time values for the ftp source and destination paths